# variadic template and std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, std-function

In the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... t>
class a {
 public:
  explicit a(std::function<std::tuple<t...>()>&& p_d,
             std::function<bool(t...)>&& p_f)
      : m_d(std::move(p_d)), m_f(std::move(p_f)) {}

  bool operator()() { return m_f(m_d()); }

 private:
  std::function<std::tuple<t...>()> m_d;
  std::function<bool(t...)> m_f;
};

class d {
  std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&> operator()() {
    return std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&>(-9, 3.14, "olá!");
  }
};

class f {
  bool operator()(int p_i, float p_f, std::string&& p_s) {
    std::cout << "i = " << p_i << ", f = " << p_f << ", s = " << p_s
              << std::endl;
    return true;
  }
};

int main() {
  d _d;
  f _f;
  typedef a<int, float, std::string&&> a_t;

  a_t _a(std::move(_d), std::move(_f));

  _a();

  return 0;
}
```

I get the compiler error:

```
../untitled014/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../untitled014/main.cpp:38:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘a<int, float, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>::a(std::remove_reference<d&>::type, std::remove_reference<f&>::type)’
   a_t _a(std::move(_d), std::move(_f));
                                      ^
../untitled014/main.cpp:8:12: note: candidate: a<t>::a(std::function<std::tuple<_Elements ...>()>&&, std::function<bool(t ...)>&&) [with t = {int, float, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&}]
   explicit a(std::function<std::tuple<t...>()>&& p_d,
            ^
../untitled014/main.cpp:8:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::remove_reference<d&>::type {aka d}’ to ‘std::function<std::tuple<int, float, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>()>&&’
```

I do not understand why the compiler can not find a suitable conversion, as it is reported in the last line of the error.

I am using g++ with flag '-std=c++14' on a Xubuntu box, and 'g++ --version' reports 'g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609'

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Regardless of the rest of the issues, your `d::operator()` gives a dangling reference to `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least three errors in your code.

In no particular order...

(1) if you want a functional, the `operator()` has to be `public`; you make they both `private`

```
class d { // default for a class is private, so operator() is private
  std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&> operator()() {
    return std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&>(-9, 3.14, "olá!");
  }
};

class f { // default per a class is private, so operator() is private
  bool operator()(int p_i, float p_f, std::string&& p_s) {
    std::cout << "i = " << p_i << ", f = " << p_f << ", s = " << p_s
              << std::endl;
    return true;
  }
};
```

You can solve this problem making `operator()`'s `public` or, maybe simpler, making `d` and `f` `struct`s.

(2) `"olá!"` isn't a valid value to initialize a `std::string &&`

```
 std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&>(-9, 3.14, "olá!");
```

You can compile with

```
 std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&>(-9, 3.14, std::string{"olá!"});
```

but this is wrong idea because, this way, you initialize an object with a reference to an object that is destroyed immediately after and you obtain a dangling reference inside the tuple.

Isn't clear to me why you want to use a `std::string &&` in the tuple but I suspect that you can use a `std::string`, not a reference to it. In all your code, non only in this function.

In this case, the following code

```
std::tuple<int, float, std::string>(-9, 3.14, "olá!");
```

works.

If you really want a reference to a `std::string` in your tuple, you have to pass a reference to an object with a lifetime long enough to cover the lifetime of you tuple.

(3) The `operator()` of `d` return a `std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&>` where the `operator()` of `f` accept three parameters: a `int`, a `float` and a `std::string&&`.

So you can't simply pass the value returned from the first to the second, without unpacking the `std::tuple` is some way, as you do in the `a::operator()`

```
bool operator()() { return m_f(m_d()); }
// ........................^^^^^^^^^^  Wrong!
```

You're using C++14 so you can't use `std::apply()` (available starting from C++17)

```
bool operator()() { return std::apply(m_f, m_d()); }
// ........................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Starting from C++17
```

so you have to emulate is in some way (`std::make_index_sequence`, `std::index_sequence`, `std::get()`, etc.).

By example

```
  bool operator() ()
   { return call(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(t)>{}); }

  template <std::size_t ... Is>
  auto call (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   {
     auto tmp { m_d() }; // so m_d() is called only one time

     return m_f(static_cast<t>(std::get<Is>(tmp))...);
   }
```

where `call()` can be `private`

Comment: About (1), I just missed that the 'f::opertator()()' and 'd::operator()()' were private... (too) beginner's mistake! 8).  I did not know about (2), thanks for the info.  About (3), the main issue, to maintain compatibility with C++ 11, I decided to change to 'bool f::operator()(std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&>&&)'.

Comment: Uh, what in (2)? Yours immediately leaks? Like, never, ever write `* new X`.

Comment: @max66 (2) is memory leak! There's no reason for dynamic allocation here. `std::tuple<int, float, std::string&&>(-9, 3.14f,std::string{"olá!"});` is perfectly valid as `std::string{"olá!"}` is an R-value.

Comment: @Quimby ... and that is a dangling reference.

Comment: @Barry oh, you are right. But in that case `std::string&&>(-9, 3.14f,"olá!");` is dangling reference too, right? Because in tuple's ctor there will be something like `std::string&& member = "olá!"` which also creates temp.

Comment: @Quimby Yep, I left the same comment on the question.

Comment: I see the leak, but ```std::string{"olá!"}``` does not seem to work. Line 42 at https://www.pastiebin.com/5b840570277cd causes a SIGABORT, while ```std::move(*(new std::string{ "olá!" }))``` does not.  If I change line 42 to ```std::string s = std::move(std::get<2>(p));```,  ```s``` is empty.

Comment: @Barry I see it now, what would be your solution here, please? Using `const char*` instead of `std::string&&` should be correct and OP doesn't use any string methods anyway. Or have `std::string` in the tuple? Then optionally specialize apply function for r-value tuples, which would move from its members?  `std::apply` probably does that.

Comment: @canellas Yes, because dangling reference.

Comment: @Quimby Yes, just `std::string`.

Comment: @Barry - you're right obviously; my first version was `std::string{"ola!"}` but was even worse (dangling reference). But... there is a correct way to feed a tuple with `std::string &&` or is wrong the same idea of a `std::string &&` in a tuple?

Comment: @max66 If you don't already have an object, you shouldn't be return a reference (regardless of reference category).

Comment: @canellas - answer modified, in point (2), following the Barry's correction (but you have just seen it).